# Making text overlap in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with two types of rows: "Parent"-rowswithout vertical cell borders and "Child"-rowswhich are just normal rows. The parent rows only have content in their first cell.

For the parent rows, I'd like the text to behave as if there weren't any other cells in the row, just overlapping.
Other cells still need to be truncated.

I did not find any option to either make the content overlap or change the width of just these specific cells.

Comment: ColSpan is not really supported for DGVs. You could do this: In the CellPainting event suppress any painting using `e.Handled = true` for each Cell you want to span its neighbour. And in the Paint event loop over the rows and cell you want to span and use `dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(cell.ColumnIndex, cell.RowIndex, true);` to get the Rectanlge(s) of those cells. Then combine their width and DrawString your text into that rectangle, maybe with a centered StringFormat..

Comment: [DataGridVewTextBoxCell with Span Behaviour](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34037/DataGridVewTextBoxCell-with-Span-Behaviour)